# Выделить повторяющееся слово в строчке со словами через _, используя regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, замена

Есть строка `proba_m4050_434_3g3_3g3.png`

Хотелось бы подобрать регулярное выражение, чтобы выделить последнее `_3g3` и заменить на пустоту (`proba_m4050_434_3g3.png`).
Проблема в том, что таких строк много (поэтому пробую пакетное переименование), части навроде `3g3` могут состоять не всегда из трёх символов, а в некоторых файлов и вовсе нет дублирующей части, то есть они сразу выглядит так, как мне нужно.

Все файлы начинаются с `proba_m`, части отделяются нижним подчеркиванием.

В тех ответах, что находил ранее, выражение рассматривало строчку, где слова отделяются пробелом, что не мой случай.

Пример ожидаемого преобразования

Было:

```
proba_m4050_434_3g3_3g3.png
proba_m313_313.png
proba_m5214_2520_gb54_gb54.png
proba_m141_18d5_fd071_fd071.png
proba_m312_534_430_39g.png
proba_m3501_5721.png
```

Стало:

```
proba_m4050_434_3g3.png 
proba_m313.png
proba_m5214_2520_gb54.png
proba_m141_18d5_fd071.png 
proba_m312_534_430_39g.png (нет дублирования, без изменений)
proba_m3501_5721.png (нет дублирования, без изменений)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше примеров входящих и выходящих данных.

Comment: @UModeL Добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать [обратные ссылки (backreferences)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences).
Само регулярное выражение получается тривиальным:

```
(_\w+)\1+
```

Квантификатор `+` в конце позволяет находить не только две повторяющиеся последовательности, а любое их количество. Если принципиально только две, то `+` можно убрать.

Замену производим не на пустую строку, а на захваченную группу.

[**Проверка**](https://regex101.com/r/xVOzBN/1)

Чтобы ограничить поиск только в конце наименования (перед расширением), нужно дополнить выражение:

```
(_\w+)\1+\.
```

Замена производится на захваченную группу с точкой `$1.`

[**Проверка**](https://regex101.com/r/xVOzBN/2)

Comment: Большое спасибо, это именно то, что было нужно!